# Show that for all $z$, $\overline{e^z} = e^\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Show that for all $z$, $\overline{e^z} = e^\bar{z}$

I'm a little stuck with this one.

First defined the following to help solve it:
$$
z = a + bi
$$
then plugging that in to the question gives
$$
\overline{e^{a + bi}} = e^\overline{a + bi}
$$

which can then be simplified to
$$
\overline{e^a(cos(b) + i sin(b))} = e^{a - bi}
$$
and so,
$$
e^a(cos(b) - isin(b)) = e^a(cos(-b) + isin(-b))
$$
therefore
$$
cos(b) - isin(b) = cos(-b) + isin(-b)
$$

But these are unequal to eachother, are they not? I must've made a mistake somewher, but I cant figure out where.

Comment: Note that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: They are equal. The cosine is an even function, and the sine is odd.

Comment: It's also bad form to start with the thing that you're trying to prove and then derive something true from it.  You should start with the true statement $\cos b-i\sin b=\cos(-b)+i\sin(-b)$ and derive $\overline{e^{a+bi}}=e^{\overline{a+bi}}$ from it. Or since you never move things around in the equation, you can format the argument as one long equation: $\overline{e^{a+bi}}=\cdots=\cos b-i\sin b=\cos(-b)+i\sin(-b)=\cdots=e^{\overline{a+bi}}$.

Comment: This is true for any power series with real coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using the power series.  Let

$$e^z = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

and let $\sigma(z) = \overline{z}$ denote complex conjugation.
Since complex conjugation is continuous, it commutes with limits of sequences:

$$\sigma(e^z) = \sigma( \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!}) = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sigma \Big(\sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!} \Big).$$

Since $\sigma$ preserves addition and multiplication, and fixes real numbers, we have

$$\sigma \Big(\sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{z^n}{n!} \Big) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^N  \frac{\sigma(z)^n}{n!} .$$

Therefore,

$$\overline{e^z} = \sigma(e^z) = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^N \frac{\sigma(z)^n}{n!} = e^{\sigma(z)} = e^{\overline{z}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \overline{e^{x + iy}} = 
\overline {e^x \times e^{iy}} = 
\overline {e^x \times [\cos(y) + i\sin(y)]}$

$\displaystyle = e^x \times [\cos(y) - i\sin(y)].$

---

$\displaystyle e^{\overline{x + iy}}
= e^{x - iy} = e^x \times e^{-iy}
= e^x \times [\cos(-y) + i\sin(-y)]$

$\displaystyle = e^x \times [\cos(y) - i\sin(y)].$